# Impossible capture white space from a string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have this two lines on a html:

```
<li><strong>Brand: </strong><em>i cant get this one</em>
<li><strong>Brand: </strong><em>this second one works</em>
```

I want to get the value **i can't get this one**, but after the first "Brand: " I have this empty space that I can't get with regex, that is the major problem.

I posted on **phpliveregex** for someone who want's to help me with this regex: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hkr

Problem: I can't capture the **first empty space*** after the word "Brand:"

I need to capture this space from hell but until now only (..) was able to get something...

Ps. I am trying for a few hours...

Comment: Please update your question with expected output. Seems there is something more wrong with it `[<\/a-z>$]*`

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided by the phpliveregex link, the first character which looks like a space is not an actual white character.
It is the extended ASCII character #255 (0xFF).

You can update your regex like this to handle it:

```
Brand:(\s| )[<\/a-z>$]*(?P<brand>[\w\s]*)<
          ^--- This is NOT a space character
```

see example here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hkJ

---

EDIT: the extended ASCII character #255 is a non breaking space. see http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/non-breaking-space-no-break-space-ascii-code-255.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can work.

if you want to get the text between `<em></em>` you can try this regex `<em>(.*)<\/em>` check this [link](https://regex101.com/r/zJA9tE/2) (it's a regex tester)

Btw, if you want to capture the space after `brand:` you can try this (check the tester [link](https://regex101.com/r/j6Swqr/1))

```
Brand:(\s+)
```